# Traverse into each hyperlink retrieve by R

Tags: r, xpath, traversal

This is my code:

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
url.link <- 'http://www.jamesaltucher.com/sitemap.xml'
blog <- getURL(url.link)
blog          <- htmlParse(blog, encoding = "UTF-8")
titles  <- xpathSApply (blog ,"//loc",xmlValue)             ## titles
```

Currently, I can correctly fetch the links inside `titles`.

I want to go inside each link and scrape the content of each blogpost to do keyword frequency counting.

I believe my pseudocode is basically.

1. for each entry in `titles`
2. take the entry and retrieve the HTML markup
3. parse the markup and extract the content under the `div id="mainContent"`

**How do I proceed with step 1 and 2 of my pseudocode in R?**

This is a screenshot of my progress so far:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want?

The function `foo` takes in an element `x`, retrieves the html object, assigns to `tmp`. Then `xpathApply(tmp, '//div[@id="mainContent"]')` says take the `tmp` object, and get the `div` element that has the id `mainContent`. That's it.  The `lapply` line passes a list of objects through the `foo()` function., so you should get a list of length `titles` of the html objects you want.

```
foo <- function(x){
  tmp <- htmlParse(x)
  xpathApply(tmp, '//div[@id="mainContent"]')
}
lapply(titles[2:3], foo)
```

Comment: Could you attach some explanation to deconstruct the code? I am not very familiar with Python or R. Thank you. For e.g., what does titles[2:3] mean?

Comment: See introduction to subsetting [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html). titles[2:3] means the 2nd and 3rd element in the titles object. The first was just the root url (the landing page for the site, so I thought you wouldn't want that). Sure, will annotate with more explanation

Comment: I may have some follow-up questions. Let me take some time to digest this. Thank you, Scott!

Comment: Okay I understand this code more or less. I just have 1 follow up 1 question. How do I "see" the content that is extracted when I run lapply?

Comment: Try `out <- lapply(titles[2:3], foo)`, then out[1] will give you the first element. Which you can then parse further.